# Не могу разобраться с кавычками " " & ' '

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

С клиентской части пересылаю данные на сервер,где записываю в db.

```
  var pool = require('./connect').pool;
  var promise = require('promise');

 module.exports.insert = function DateInstert(msg,na,nameChat){
pool.connect(function(err,client,done){
    client.query('WITH userid AS(' +
        'INSERT INTO public.users(nickname) VALUES (' + na + ') RETURNING id)' +
        'INSERT INTO public.chat("nameChat", user_id) SELECT ' +nameChat+ ', id FROM userid;' +
        'INSERT INTO public.message(user_id_send, user_id_get,group_id, text 
  VALUES (4, 2, 0,' + msg +');')
  });
   console.log(msg);
   }
```

Ошибка:
(node:4764) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "VALU
ES")

Проблема в кавычках? Просит двойные, а как тогда размместить сам запрос? ПРобовал поменять на одинарные весь запрос и двойные в таблицу,ничего не вышло.

Comment: Вы написали решение проблемы прямо в вопросе. Почему у вас ничего не вышло - непонятно, покажите код, в котором ничего не вышло

Comment: Проблема в запросе, ему не нравится синтаксис

Comment: Тот код, который вы сейчас показали, точно выдаёт именно эту ошибку?

Comment: немного переделав, выдает описанное выше ошибку.

Comment: Никогда не пишите значения переменных непосредственно в текст запроса. Используйте привязку переменных https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values (читать со слов "_Alternatively, you can use `?` characters as placeholders for values_"

Answer (score 0):

```
Вот так решил эту проблему

var shouldAbort = function(err) {
if (err) {
    console.error('Error in transaction', err.stack);
    pool.connect(function(err,client,done){
    client.query('ROLLBACK', function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error rolling back client', err.stack);
        }
        // release the client back to the pool
        done();
    })
})
    pool.end();
}
return !!err;
}



module.exports.insert = function DateInstert(msg,na,nameChat){

pool.connect(function(err,client,done){


    client.query('BEGIN', function(err) {
if (shouldAbort(err)) return;
client.query('INSERT INTO public.users("nickname") VALUES($1) RETURNING id', [na], function(err, res){
    if (shouldAbort(err)) return;

    var insertPhotoText = 'INSERT INTO public.chat("nameChat", user_id) VALUES ($1, $2)';
    var insertPhotoValues = [nameChat,res.rows[0].id];

    var insertmsg = 'INSERT INTO public.message(user_id_send, user_id_get,group_id, text) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)';
    var insertValue = [4, 2, 0, msg];

    client.query(insertPhotoText, insertPhotoValues, function(err, res) {
        if (shouldAbort(err)) return;

        client.query(insertmsg, insertValue, function (err, res) {
            if (shouldAbort(err)) return;

            client.query('COMMIT', function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error('Error committing transaction', err.stack)
                }
                done();
            })
          })
         })
        })
       })
      })
     }
```